# Google Map Search with Lat/Long not correct

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In our case, we have a google map displaying our product.  There is a search field.  If the end user puts in a address, it  geolocates that on the map without issues.  If the end user puts in a GPS location (not address) it does return a result but it is off of the proper location.  The issue is sometimes users put in a GPS location, and sometimes an address.  The address is fine cause we don't know their exact GPS, but if they put in the exact GPS, it should find them on that GPS location, right now it returns about a 1/2 mile away from where the actual location is per the map.

Comment: When I goto maps.google.com and put in a GPS in the serach, its right on the home in question.  When I do ours, its out in the field next to it, a bit off.  Our programmer came up with a address/geocodes method, i.e. you can select if its address or not, but i would not think that has to work that way.

Comment: What does the code look like that does the geocoding?

Comment: Google does the geocoding, guess I was hoping for a link to show how we can send it to google in various forms.  i.e.  how does google understand the differance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Google does the geocoding"?  What does your code look like that get that data from "Google"?  Which API are you using?    How are you using it?  Are you calling it differently with an address or a set of GPS coordinates?

Comment: Think this is the same issue as looking up 52.258072,4.965595 on GoogleMaps/BingMaps and Geoplaner.com The results are different.